# How to make the row fill the screen width with some padding using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13

I am trying to create a list with cards or rows which grows downwards. It's added to a horizontal scroll view which can have multiple lists.

[image: snap]

How to make the card fill the width - some padding of the screen?

The current code is

```
struct RowView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)  // shows a square, but how to set size depending on screen?
        //.frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)  // nothing shows up
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                RowView()
                RowView()
                RowView()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ListView()
                ListView()
                ListView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using `GeometryReader`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using `GeometryReader`, but it's not working.

It's important in which `View` component you tried `GeometryReader`.

- If you are inside a typical `View` that spans up to the screen's size, you get the `width` & `height` of the screen itself.
- If you are inside a `ScrollView` environment, you get

  - `height` of the container in case of `.horizontal` alignment
  - `width` of the container in case of `.vertical` alignment

---

I can't actually visualize what you are trying to achieve with both `.horizontal` & `.vertical` aligned scroll views. But what you said about the **Card** like view to be spanned all the way up to the screen width, you can achieve it by using below code: (see the inline comments for better understanding)

```
struct RowView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(height: 150)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // you won't get the width of the container if you embed this view inside a horizontal scroll view which is the case for you
        // so you have to impose the explicit width from the parent view
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                RowView()
                RowView()
                RowView()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    // you have to be explicit about the width of each content of the scroll view as it can't determine width of each content by itself
                    ListView().frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                    ListView().frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                    ListView().frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fill the width of the screen, you can add a GeometryReader to the ContentView and use it to set the width of the HStack.  Set the padding there as well.

(The order of padding and frame is important, as is the placement of the GeometryReader to pick up the screen width.)

As to the height, that can be set directly to the Rectangle.  You have several options here that have similar effects.  Since you said the list will be growing downward and the Rectangles are in a ScrollView, it would make sense to set a fixed height.

```
struct RowView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(height: 100)
            //.frame(idealHeight: 100)
            //.frame(minHeight: 100)
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                RowView()
                RowView()
                RowView()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ListView()
                    ListView()
                    ListView()
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. If I understand correctly that you want to fill the screen horizontally and will grow the list only downward, you may not need the horizontal ScrollView in the ContentView.  But, if that's not what you're trying to do, please clarify as this solution may not achieve what you want.