# Setting View frame based on GeometryReader located inside that View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

As a part of my effort to learn new technologies, I'm trying to implement one of the screens of an app I'm working on in SwiftUI. I have this rough layout:

[image]

This element should stretch to accommodate the container size (devices of different widths) and will be used in a ScrollView.

Here's the preliminary solution I came up with after some stumbling around:

[image]

This works well enough for the first attempt but I want to refactor the View by moving all the relevant parts into a separate View. In addition to that, I want that new view to automatically account for paddings and other size modification I might add later.

So, here's a naive rewrite:

[image]

As you can readily spot, GeometryReader inside ScrollView assumed the size the parent provided it, effectively hiding most of the View.

There are several "dirty" solutions to this situation: set a fixed frame height to the View, set an aspect ratio that would approximate the correct size (a bit tricky given that there are Text views with fixed heights), keep GeometryReader as the outermost element of the main view and pass the width to the subview as an initialization parameter.

I'm looking for a "clean" solution for this particular layout and, perhaps, for a more general understanding about how Views is SwiftUI regulate their sizes – in WWDC videos it is said that parent View proposes a size but then child View returns it's own size; is there a way to interfere in that process somehow or is it all done through private APIs?

Thank you!

–Baglan

p.s. I thought code screenshot besides the UI preview would be the most illustrative but let me know if I should provide code snippets as well!

Comment: screenshots are good, but your rating will drop because  others will hit downvote button due to lack of code

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind for my future submissions!

Answer (score 3):

This code works fine:

```swift
struct GeometryReaderExperiment: View {
    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in

            ScrollView {

                Text("First")

                DesignedFancy(parentGeometry: geometry, rectangleColor: .red)

                Text("Second")

                DesignedFancy(parentGeometry: geometry, rectangleColor: .green)

                Text("Third")

                DesignedFancy(parentGeometry: geometry, rectangleColor: .blue)

            }

        }

    }
}

struct DesignedFancy: View {

    var parentGeometry: GeometryProxy
    var rectangleColor: Color

    var body: some View {

        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                    .foregroundColor(rectangleColor)

                Text("One")
            }
            .frame(width: parentGeometry.size.width * 2/3)

            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .foregroundColor(rectangleColor)
                Text("Two")
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I think the problem is that `DesignedFancy` doesn't know how much space it has. Therefore, you must provide this information through a variable. The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It definitely works and it, effectively, mirrors my initial attempt (I've outlined this approach in the paragraph where I was exploring "dirty" solutions). One of the problems with it is if you later decide to add a padding to the contents of the ScrollView – as GeometryReader only gets the outer-most dimensions, you would have to explicitly account for paddings.

That said, if a better solution could not be found, I was considering going with this approach.

Again, thank you!

Comment: as post owner said this is 'dirty' solution, he's finding 'clean' solution. But I agree with you that DesignedFancy view doesn't know it size for layout before generate there children

Comment: I think GeometryReader has the ability to "know" the sizes of it's children, after all, say, VStack "knows" that and sets it's size accordingly, I think it's more of a design consideration for the GeometryReader – it only exposes the size the parent proposes. I think sizes are accessible internally but are not exposed. It is possible that this sort of layout can't be realized fully with SwiftUI as it exists now.

Answer (score 3):

I believe my answer is supposed to be a comment, but as it's going to be a lengthy one, I'm posting this as an answer. I answer a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58230599/3687801) if that can bring more light.

It's important in which `View` component you are using `GeometryReader`.

- If you are inside a typical `View` that spans up to the screen's size, you get the `width` & `height` of the screen itself.
- If you are inside a `ScrollView` environment, you get

  - `height` of the container in case of `.horizontal` alignment
  - `width` of the container in case of `.vertical` alignment

Typically, `ScrollView` without specifying alignment explicitly defaults to `.vertical`.

---

I suppose, the design decision is correct. Because there is a **Content View** in a Scroll View if you recall `UIScrollView` from `UIKit`. You don't know the size of the **Content View** in advance until you add some contents. In `SwiftUI`, the `GeometryReader` inside `ScrollView` mimics the mathematics of the **Content View** from `UIScrollView`. And that is the reason, you don't get the actual size from geometry reader.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for explaining related concepts! If I understood it correctly, in context of my question, it means that this sort of layout is not achievable in the current iteration of SwiftUI without some "hacks" (such as passing container width as a parameter), please feel free to correct me if my interpretation is wrong!

Comment: @Baglan, yes! You are correct with your interpretation. `GeometryReader` & `ScrollView` aren't mutually compatible as of now.